# Bundle invalid payload reason: 0x80070570

Tags: installation, wix, bundle, sign, bootstrapper

Wix 3.6. I'm trying to run a bundle :

```
<Bundle Name="Setup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Bentley" UpgradeCode="37d68094-0b98-4b16-bfbe-7f0d3015064a">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="path/to/MyMsiFileWhichIsFine.msi" Cache="yes" Compressed="no" InstallCondition="1"/>
    </Chain>
```

Result from execution :

```
0x800b0109 A certification chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

The log file says :

```
Detected partially cached package: MyMsiFileWhichIsFine.msi, invalid payload: MyMsiFileWhichIsFine.msi, reason: 0x80070570
```

I signed this msi. The bootstrapper was also signed using (cf this [link](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2012/05/wix-burn-tipstricks.html)):

```
insignia -ib Setup.exe -o engine.exe
signtool engine.exe (extra parameters excluded for simplicity)
insignia -ab engine.exe Setup.exe -o Setup.exe
signtool Setup.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution ! I just skip the signing verification like this :

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="MyPath\MyFileToLaunch.exe" Compressed="no" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the msi was created externally rather than using Heat.exe that comes as part of WIX. I've had similar issues when I was trying to work with VB6 files, and had to add in flags to ignore those checks. But in  your case, Bootstrapper might not be able to interpret the msi correctly. How did the msi get created? Did  you use Heat? Can you post the Heat lines if so?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I used candle then light to create the msi. I plan to add a .exe written in C# .Net 3.5 in this bootstraper. I compiled everything (including the above) in command line. What is Heat  ? How should I use it in this case ?

Comment: [Heat](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html)  is a tool used for harvesting files into an MSI. It will create wxs file (which is a list of files)) to include in an Product.wxs which contains the definition of how the installer will run and install stuff. On a side note you could try running orca and msiexec to see/extract file? It might be worth doing a spike on Heat and/or setup project to create the msi if you have the time.

Comment: If I have time I'll have a look at it. In the meanwhile I tried to replace the msi file to launch by the exe I just mentioned. The result is exactly the same.