# Wix - bundle with customized image banner, license agreement, and possibly other etc

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, wix

After having finally solved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733259/wix-bundle-invalid-payload-reason-0x80070570), I am now customizing the bootstrapper UI and license page in Wix 3.7.

How do I change the image banner in the bootstrapper ? How do I skip the license agreement either in the bootstrapper or in the loaded msi ? What can I customize more ?

Answer (score 2):

To change the banner image, [set the `LogoFile` attribute](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_branding.html).

To skip the license agreement in the bootstrapper, [use a `HyperlinkLicense` UI and omit the `LicenseUrl` attribute](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_license.html).

If you use the `HyperlinkLicense` UI, you also [customize the side logo with the `LogoSideFile` attribute](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_branding.html).